# Space separated csv with spaces in column names and values

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have to load a csv file to dataframe but the columns are separated with single spaces and also contain spaces in columns/values names. File looks like that:

```
'Mod Ports Card Type                              Model              Serial No.',
'  3   20  7600 ES+                               7600-ES+20G3C      SAL1550Y9DL',
'  5    2  Route Switch Processor 720 (Active)    RSP720-3C-GE       SAL16095Q9W',
etc.
```

My best idea so far was to check for length of the word in the column name and then check if the corresponding values lower has bigger of lower number of characters but in some cases like 'Card Type' and '7600 ES+' could be potentially recognized as 2 separate columns.

What's important is that this solution has to be universal and work not only for this example but for different ones too. My goal is to read this file to dataframe or any other data structure.

I tried to use the `pd.read_fwf()` function but it gives incorrect results. The output dataframe for my file looks like that:

[image: wrong output]

So not only it didn't catch the `Card type` correctly but it merged it with ports and created some Unnamed columns.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Please share the code to reproduce your attempt and explain why it does not work.

Comment: Frankly I was not able to code anything that works even remotely. All I have is concept but I know that it won't work in all cases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to make dataframe because read\_csv whitespace separation not constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44420656/unable-to-make-dataframe-because-read-csv-whitespace-separation-not-constant)

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work and returns dataframe with 'Unnamed: 2' etc. columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [read_fwf()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html):

```
df = pd.read_fwf('my_file.csv')
```

It will work the best if you provide it with `widths` parameter for each column.

**EDIT**

Using the data you provided you can get results with `colspecs` parameter:

```
df = pd.read_fwf(a, colspecs=[(0, 4), (4, 10), (10, 49), (49, 68), (68, 1000)])
df

   Mod  Ports                            Card Type          Model   Serial No.
0    3     20                             7600 ES+  7600-ES+20G3C  SAL1550Y9DL
1    5      2  Route Switch Processor 720 (Active)   RSP720-3C-GE  SAL16095Q9W
```

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that I don't know these widths as it's not the only table that I have to process that looks like that. This solution won't work unless I have some way to predict this size automatically.

Comment: @TheFirstTransistor Well you can check the first line of file and see what is the number of characters (including whitespace) that each column occupies.

Comment: I'm still not sure how you want to do that. I mean how would I classify what stand for separate columns. 'Card' and 'Type' could very well be names of separate columns, but they are not.

Comment: Didn't work when I tried without the widths parameter. :(

Comment: Yes but in this case you assume I know the width of each column. What I need is a solution that can work on many files with different widths by itself.